# Get result of macro in a cell in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, cookies

When I run the code I get the result in the immediate window using `Debug.Print (cookieValues)`.

**My request**

I need that result in the `A1` cell of `Sheet1`.

I used `MsgBox (cookieValues)` in the place of `Debug.Print (cookieValues)` thinking to get the result into MsgBox and then get it into cell A1, but that failed.

**What my Code does**

Fetches cookies value from a site and gives output as shown below in result.

**The Code**

```vb
Public Function NSEDataCall(website, setCookies) As String

Dim XMLHTTP As WinHttp.WinHttpRequest

'Initialize XMLHttp Object
'Use the best/proper XMLHttp object available on your system
Set XMLHTTP = CreateObject("WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1") ' needs Microsoft WinHTTP Services 5.1 reference
    
' XMLHTTP.Option(WinHttpRequestOption_EnableRedirects) = False ' WinHttpRequestOption_EnableRedirects=6
        
XMLHTTP.Open "GET", website, False
    
' Set headers.
XMLHTTP.setRequestHeader "REFERER", website
XMLHTTP.setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1)"
XMLHTTP.setRequestHeader "Accept", "text/xml,application/xml,application/xhtml+xml,text/html;q=0.9,text/plain;q=0.8,image/png,*/*;q=0.5"
XMLHTTP.setRequestHeader "Accept-Language", "en-us,en;q=0.5"
XMLHTTP.setRequestHeader "Accept-Charset", "ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7"

' Set cookie value - used for second call
If Len(setCookies) > 0 Then
    XMLHTTP.setRequestHeader "cookie", setCookies
Else
End If

XMLHTTP.send

If Len(setCookies) > 0 Then

    ' Get response headers
    response = XMLHTTP.getAllResponseHeaders
    ' Debug.Print response

    ' Split by new line
    responseArray = Split(response, vbCrLf)
    ' Debug.Print responseArray(7)

    ' Helps to identify dataType - output comes as code numbers
    ' MsgBox (VarType(Trim(Split(Split(responseArray(5), ";")(0), ":")(1)) & "; " & Trim(Split(Split(responseArray(6), ";")(0), ":")(1))

    ' Return the sv_bm cookie in response array from indices 7 (indices start from 0)
    NSEDataCall = setCookies & "; " & Trim(Split(Split(responseArray(7), ";")(0), ":")(1))
   
Else

    ' Get response headers
    response = XMLHTTP.getAllResponseHeaders
    ' Debug.Print response

    ' Split by new line
    responseArray = Split(response, vbCrLf)

    ' Helps to identify dataType - output comes as code numbers
    ' MsgBox (VarType(Trim(Split(Split(responseArray(5), ";")(0), ":")(1)) & "; " & Trim(Split(Split(responseArray(6), ";")(0), ":")(1))

    ' Return the cookies in response array from indices 5 to 9
    NSEDataCall = Trim(Split(Split(responseArray(5), ";")(0), ":")(1)) & "; " & Trim(Split(Split(responseArray(6), ";")(0), ":")(1)) & "; " & Trim(Split(Split(responseArray(7), ";")(0), ":")(1)) & "; " & Trim(Split(Split(responseArray(8), ";")(0), ":")(1)) & "; " & Trim(Split(Split(responseArray(9), ";")(0), ":")(1))
    'Debug.Print (responseArray(5) + responseArray(6))

End If
End Function


' My Macro
Sub GetNSECookies()

Dim website As String
Dim cookieValues As String
Dim website2 As String
Dim cookieValuesFinal As String

' First call
website = "https://www.nseindia.com/market-data/securities-lending-and-borrowing"
cookieValues = NSEDataCall(website, cookieValues)
' Debug.Print (cookieValues)

' Second call for sv_bm cookie
website = "https://www.nseindia.com/market-data/securities-lending-and-borrowing"
cookieValues = NSEDataCall(website, cookieValues)

'Shows value in Immediate window
Debug.Print (cookieValues)

End Sub
```

The result of code shown in the Immediate window

> nsit=p8XRMHoQSM5uEQUM7XIJdT8B; nseappid=eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInUl2PkrpgUZp9w8r1UF-yXGo4Os; AKA_A2=A; ak_bmsc=520CE4F35658A3B15048CCCE60A4E7547D38DEAjbZNKcjEdm4LTLidgmXX0=; bm_mi=C5AE845425DB55CAB9626B7A4DD0F7FD~D8U6FxMuj0HFHR1iPY=; bm_sv=E2881456097AB72A45E379FB86952E6f7nV/M=

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace this line `Debug.Print (cookieValues)` with

```
Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1")= cookieValues
```

Comment: It works great! thanks but I have one concern Instead of your given code I used `Range("Cookie[cookie]") = cookieValues` as I did some changes like I converted cell `A1` & `A2` in the table and I found that my current cell where I want my data is looking like ``Range("Cookie[cookie]")` currently it is working right, but is there anything wrong in it according to VBA code so that it doesn't start giving errors later.